# Receiving a casting error message during execution

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

This is my first foray into using NSubstitute.

I am trying to emulate a routine returning a 409 - Conflict error on a web call.

```
WebResponse response = Substitute.For<WebResponse>();
((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode.Returns(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
return (response);
```

The code compiles cleanly, but upon execution the setting of the status code throws this:

Unable to cast object of type Castle.Proxies.WebResponse Proxy to type 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse'

Do I have some sort of syntax issue with my casting?

Thanks.

Bryan Hunt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, [`HttpWebResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse?view=net-7.0) is a derived class from `WebResponse`, so exception is correct. You might do a mock of `HttpWebResponse` instead:

```
var response = Substitute.For<HttpWebResponse>();
response.StatusCode.Returns(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
...
```

Comment: That worked, thanks very much.  The method normally returns a WebResponse, so I thought that I needed to mangle it to be a WebResponse.  When I did a return response; I was expecting to get a type mismatch, but I didn't.  I assume that is because HttpWebResponse is derived from WebResponse it is okay to return it instead?

Comment: @BryanHunt, it's ok to return HttpWebResponse if uri is `https://..` or `http://..` . Because as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-8.0#examples `If the scheme for the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is http:// or https://, WebRequest.Create returns an HttpWebRequest object.`